# Scalable chat site in python

Tags: python, chat, chatroom

Hey guys, I have an idea that I'd like to start implementing that at the crux of it, will basically be a chat website, and will need to support multiple rooms. Quite frankly, I'm not too sure where to begin with regards to setting up a very sturdy/scalable chat system in python (or another language if you guys believe it to be a better alternative), so any suggestions that can get me pointed in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into XMPP. Here's the [list of Python libraries](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml#python).

Answer (score 0):

Google AppEngine supports python provides scalable framework. Probably you'll save lots of time if you use it.